# Images displayed based on even or odd minutes

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a newbie and have spent much time trying to figure this out on my own..
Check out this [page](http://toptwosellers.com/dog-beds/).
It shows two images in wordpress.
My goal is to have half the visitors that land on this page to see the images as you see them. Which is Ad1 first and Ad2 second.
And the other half of visitors to see Ad2 first and Ad1 second.
The approach I'm trying is to use minutes of the hour. 
Even minutes render the page one way. Odd minutes render the other way.
When a page is loaded, I can find the current minute using the following code:

```
var d = new Date()
var n = d.getMinutes()
```

At this point I'm going to use the isEven or isOdd javascript function.
I'm trying to figure out how to use an If Else to display the images.
I don't know how to separate were to put the javascript and were to put the html body. Here's what I've been playing with. This is probably very basic but I just can't figure it out. I've tried the if statement in many different ways. I think the images html needs to be outside of the javascript section. How can I render the images based on an If Else.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm very confused.
I tried entering the code here but ran into an issue with doing that.
Find my code [here](http://toptwosellers.com/code/).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just place plain HTML into JS like that...

Place your elements inside your page "normally" - and add some ID selector

than inside a `<script>` tag, before the closing `</body>` tag target your ID element being suffixed `0` or `1` depending on the minutes reminder `% 2` - and add a `.hidden` class to that element.

```html
<style>
.hidden{display:none;}
</style>


<div id="ads_0">ONE (visible when minutes are odd)</div>
<div id="ads_1">TWO (visible when minutes are even)</div>


<script>
var min = new Date().getMinutes() % 2; // 0, 1, 0, 1....
document.getElementById("ads_"+ min).classList.add("hidden");
</script>
```